# Is deploying a program to a virtual machine not on my hardware count as "distribution"?

Tags: gpl, distribution, terminology

I am permitted to mix not open-source code with GPL code on my computer if I don't distribute it.

Is deploying it to a VM on a remote server considered distribution?

Comment: The GPL defines distributions in a bit of a particular way. Do you think you could perhaps tell us how the server/VM will be used? Who will it be available to?

Comment: Which version of the GPL do you want to know about? This is something that is version dependant.

Answer (score 2):

Copyright law cares about legal entities, not computers.

Unless AGPL is involved:

It doesn't matter how many different real or virtual computers are involved -- the question is, did you make it available to a different legal entity -- did you meet the legal definition of 'publication'. See [the actual definition](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/publication).

Now, for AGPL, the question will be whether you created a service open to the public -- again, completely independently of how many computers, real or virtual, were involved.

Comment: The question is clearly about the GPL not the AGPL.

Comment: Your crystal ball is more functional than mine.